# Remove specific dropdown filters from Woocommerce products admin list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce 3.5.2 and was trying to find a simple way of removing some Product Filter(s) from Products Admin screen:

[image: Product Admin:]

I would like to remove **Filter by Product Type** and **Filter by Stock Status** from the Products Admin screen. I went looking on GitHub for the answer, I found [`render_filters()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-products.php#L288-L308) function which includes [`woocommerce_products_admin_list_table_filters`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-products.php#L293) filter hook:

```
/**
 * Render any custom filters and search inputs for the list table.
 */
protected function render_filters() {
    $filters = apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_products_admin_list_table_filters',
        array(
            'product_category' => array( $this, 'render_products_category_filter' ),
            'product_type'     => array( $this, 'render_products_type_filter' ),
            'stock_status'     => array( $this, 'render_products_stock_status_filter' ),
        )
    );
    ob_start();
    foreach ( $filters as $filter_callback ) {
        call_user_func( $filter_callback );
    }
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_filters', $output ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
}
```

But I cannot find a reference to this filter hook anywhere else than in woocommerce source code, regarding the usage.

Is there a way I can use this hook to remove some product filters?

Another option I saw was from an earlier stack overflow thread and using CSS to display: 
[Remove a dropdown select field filter in Woocommerce admin orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801475/remove-a-dropdown-select-field-filter-in-woocommerce-admin-orders-list/43802387#43802387) 
I guess... doesn't feel quite right, but it does the job.

So I am asking if there is a way to use `woocommerce_products_admin_list_table_filters` filter hook to remove some product filters that I do not need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `woocommerce_products_admin_list_table_filters` hook to remove **"Product Type"** and **"Stock Status"** dropdown filters from the admin product list pages, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_admin_list_table_filters', 'remove_products_admin_list_table_filters', 10, 1 );
function remove_products_admin_list_table_filters( $filters ){
    // Remove "Product type" dropdown filter
    if( isset($filters['product_type']))
        unset($filters['product_type']);

    // Remove "Product stock status" dropdown filter
    if( isset($filters['stock_status']))
        unset($filters['stock_status']);

    return $filters;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: The code does remove 'product_type' and 'product_status', but also is removing my custom taxonomy filter that I created.  You helped me move the custom filter after product_category in an earlier SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752472/add-a-custom-taxonomy-filter-after-product-category-filter-in-woocommerce-admin